# Find a test in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have a huge project with a lot of different tests in different suites.

And I would like to find a test by name (`ClassNameTest.testMethod`) to see its history. I don't know the suite where this test is. How do I search by test name?

Just searching by test class returns all builds since they output something about this class every time.

I have tried opening test history to see if I can tweak URL, but it's in the form of `testNameId=-2327717746523985574` which is obviously useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is sort of a hack of an answer. Start by checking out the advanced search documentation:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Search

Then run a search:

```
tests:ClassNameTest.testMethod
```

In the list of results, click on a result on the right side "Tests passed:...".

[image: Step 1]

Then click on the "Tests" tab.

[image: Step 2]

Then search again for your "ClassNameTest.testMethod".

[image: Step 3]

Then finally use the dropdown to access the test history.

[image: Step 4]